# batch file Subtracting hour current time on Windows

Tags: datetime, batch-file, windows-7, date-manipulation

I need to subtract, for example, 1 hour from current time in a .bat file on Windows 7.

I do it like this.

```
set day=%date:~0,2%
set month=%date:~-7,2%
set year=%date:~-4,4%
:: ———————————————————————–
set hour=%time:~0,2%

set /A hour= hour - 1

if %hour% lss 0 set hour=23
if %hour% lss 10 set hour=0%hour%

echo %year%-%month%-%day% %hour%:00
```

But the problem, it is get consistence when the subtracting results a day before on a month before. For example, this date, **2016-03-01 00:05** I get **2016-03-01 23:05**. I need to get **2016-02-29 23:05**

I found several batch script to subtract one day, but nothing with hours or minutes.

Comment: After `if %hour% lss 0 set hour=23` you need to invoke the "subtract 1 day script" that you have found is implement that as `if %hour% lss 0 set hour=23&your_subtract_1_day_script` so that if you move back to the previous day (hour changes from 0 to 23) then, and only then invoke the script to subtract 1 day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely Batch, but I find that there are so many exceptions and special cases, that it's not worth it re-coding everything in Batch, especially when it's been done before. I like to just invoke Powershell from a batch file, like this.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')"') do echo %%a
```

Output will be something like: `2016-10-18 02:05`

Comment: This command as written will output the date in 12-hr format, so 5PM will be displayed as `05:00` not as `17:00`. The correct command is `powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')`.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are not good in date/time operations. Spend much time with similar issues, I can recommend to use external tool such (as window port of unix 'date' command for example) and perform any operations on timestamps.